# Laravel GET method for search

Tags: php, forms, laravel, get

I create form in Laravel:

```
<form action="/redeem" method="get" class="sidebar-form">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" name="key" class="form-control" placeholder="ENTER VOUCHER CODE">
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="submit" name="search" id="search-btn" class="btn btn-flat"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>
            </button>
          </span>
    </div>
  </form>
```

and now when I try to submit that I get:

```
http://localhost:8888/redeem?key=NBtGJ5pZls&search=
```

but I need to get just:

```
http://localhost:8888/redeem/NBtGJ5pZls
```

also in route I have:

```
Route::get('/redeem/{key}', 'OrdersController@redeem');
```

How to get redirected to redeem/NBtGJ5pZls with my form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your route to:

```
Route::post('/redeem', 'OrdersController@redeem');
```

And then get key in controller:

```
public function redeem(Request $request)
{
    $key = $request->key;
```

And finally, change your form:

```
<form action="/redeem" method="post" class="sidebar-form">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got 2 options:

The first is let your frontend code be the way it is, update the route, and work with the GET parameter.

The second one is using some javascript to rewrite the URL you want to access.
For example this (it's using jQuery):

```
$('#search-btn').click(function() {
    var key = $('input[name=key]').val();

    window.location.href = '/redeem/' + key;
});
```

I prefer the first one, because javascript can be modified by the end-user.